# move/unmove elements below the dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am currently working on a task where I am required that after the drop down is expanded the elements below the dropdown should not get hidden.

They should move down as the drop down expands and move up as the drop down unexpands.

Is this possible?

I have a sample code below:

```
<select id="test">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
<option value="d">D</option>
<option value="e">E</option>
</select>
<div>abc</div>
```

I want div "abc" to move down when the dropdown is expanded so that it doesnt get hidden behind dropdown options.

Once the dropdown unexpand,I want div "abc" to come back to its original position.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript that you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Yes it is possible. I would try to play around by changing the size of a containing div after the user has clicked on select. If you try something out and get stuck you can ask for more help.